# ML model deployment through h2o

Tags: h2o

I have built a machine learning model in R for Preventing Application Fraud in Loans using 
ensemble of 5 submodels. I am looking to deploy it but I am clueless how to use h2o for this. can anyone explain briefly how to use it?

Comment: Hi Sachin, when posting questions to Stack Overflow it's best to have a very specific question, for example you could post code you used to attempt to productionize your model along with the behavior you would expect and the behavor/error you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all about productionizing a model in the H2O User Guide [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html)